# decrypt with public key

Tags: encryption, go, openssl, cryptography

How can I decrypt a message signed with a private key in golang?

```
$ openssl genrsa -out ./server/server.key
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
..................+++
.............................................+++

$ openssl rsa -in ./server/server.key -pubout -out ./client/client.pub
writing RSA key

$ echo "secret" | openssl rsautl -inkey ./server/server.key -sign > ./secret

# decrypt with public key
$ openssl rsautl -inkey ./client/client.pub -pubin -in ./secret
secret
```

Comment: Did you even try looking at the documentation? https://godoc.org/crypto/rsa What have you tried that isn't working? You have posted nothing Go related.

Comment: this library can't decrypt message with public key, only verify methods

Comment: @vadv I think you misunderstand asymmetric key encryption. You encrypt with a public key, and decrypt with a private key, as you can see from the function signatures in that package - the Encrypt* functions take a public key, and the Decrypt* functions take a private key.

Comment: @Adrian 
`$ openssl rsautl -inkey ./client/client.pub -pubin -in ./secret`
return content of signed message ('secret'), how i get content with golang?

Comment: It seems like you're also confusing signing and encryption - can you clarify the question?

Comment: RSA_public_decrypt and RSA_private_encrypt used for signature in the same projects as opscode / chef for example, below I introduced a pure-go solution

Comment: The inner workings of signature verification actually do decrypt the signature with the private key and then verify the format of the result and compare the hash in the  data with the hash of the signed data. Theoretically it can be done and some implementations of signature verification actually do expose the decrypted content.

Answer (score 7):

I fully understood my question, it was about `RSA_public_decrypt` method of openssl: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/RSA_public_decrypt.html

I did not found any pure-golang realization. Realization with cgo: https://github.com/dgkang/rsa/blob/master/rsa/rsa.go

UPD, work for me:

```
func RSA_public_decrypt(pubKey *rsa.PublicKey, data []byte) []byte {
    c := new(big.Int)
    m := new(big.Int)
    m.SetBytes(data)
    e := big.NewInt(int64(pubKey.E))
    c.Exp(m, e, pubKey.N)
    out := c.Bytes()
    skip := 0
    for i := 2; i < len(out); i++ {
        if i+1 >= len(out) {
            break
        }
        if out[i] == 0xff && out[i+1] == 0 {
            skip = i + 2
            break
        }
    }
    return out[skip:]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a legitimate question because Golang's RSA package DecryptPKCS1v15 only accepts private key. No idea why you got so many down votes.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a bit of a misunderstanding here. `openssl rsautl -sign` does not encrypt the data. It produces a *signature*. The contents in your `secret` file is not "secret", encrypted. Rather, it is a signature of the text "secret" that is signed with the private key.

Using the public key, you can `-verify` the signature, but this isn't really what you are trying to do. It sounds like you want encrypt/decrypt, not sign/verify.

Use the `-encrypt` and `-decrypt` options of `rsautl`. Encryption happens with the public key, and decryption happens with the private key.

Keep in mind there are limits to the amount of data you can encrypt with RSA. Typically, you would protect a symmetric key with RSA, and use the symmetric key to do bulk encryption and decryption.

Comment: It is always worth mentioning that doing these operations yourself is difficult to get right and error prone.  I would recommend finding a tool that automates the use of public/private key encryption along with symmetric. Using raw RSA / AES by itself offers lots of mistakes.

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones
 I like to get content of signed signed message ('secret'), like in java `import javax.crypto.Cipher;` `cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` `cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, <rsaPublicKey>);` `cipher.doFinal(<digest>);`
this return 'secret'